# Unable to view the Search Center title in the results.aspx page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-results, search-center

I am having a Search Center sub-site within my SP 2013 site collection and have created filters, refiners etc.I performed `Full Crawl` and Search is working as expected.But when I navigate to the results.aspx page,I am not able to view the Title of the sub site-here Search Center.Is there any settings I need to do for enabling/to-appear the sub site title?
I have created this search center on the root web of my web app.
url : https://mysite.company.com/SC 
results url : https://mysite.company.com/SC/Pages/results.aspx?k=emp%2A

Answer (score 1):

It's the way the template is, so there is no "setting" to enable.  A few options I can think of:

1. Edit the Search page and manually place a content editor web part in there and type your Title.
2. Create a new MasterPage for your Search Template and inject the title.
3. Create a new web part page

How to create a new results page:

Add the following webparts (these are what are on a default result page):
 1. Search Box
 2. Search Navigation
 3. Search Results
 4. Refinement Panel

It will be laid out slightly different using the default web part page layouts, but it will function as you expect with your site title.

To use the page you need update Search Settings.  If this is used across site collection you need to update the settings in Central Admin, otherwise you can do it for Site collection or just the Site.  Once in Search Settings update the results page URL.

Comment: We have created a custom master page which has a banner and  within the banner the title used to be appear for my site collections.But here due to some strange reason, the title  doesn't appear.